# Automatically replace dev database with live database?

Tags: sql-server, automation, cruisecontrol.net

I have live and dev versions of an ASP.NET website, with corresponding live and dev versions of the SQL Server back end. Each is on its own server (so 4 total) on the same local network.

Every so often, we've been manually replacing the dev DB with the live DB, using backup & restore, so that the dev DB is a reasonably recent snapshot of the live DB. What's the best way to automate that process?

I'd be interested in either having it run on a schedule, or making it a pushbutton process where we still control the timing.

(For what it's worth, we use CruiseControl.net; so an option that would let us use the CC.net dashboard to launch this process would be nice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- you can use replication (transactional or snapshot) for synchronizing two databases.

2- write an application that get backup from db and restore it. (use SMO)

3- write an application that delete all data from dev db and copy all data from live db to it. you can use bcp (SQLBulkCopy) for doing this work.

Answer (score 1):

I think scheduling or automating a restore would be relatively simple with the [RESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858(SQL.90).aspx) command in T-SQL. Schedule your backups to go to a designated location and set whatever schedule / script that refreshes the dev database to look in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set up a Snapshot replication between your live and dev database? This is the way we handle keep our dev database in synch with our production database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx